# Ctypes catching exception

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I'm playing a little bit with ctypes and C/C++ DLLs
I have a quite simple "math" dll

```
double Divide(double a, double b)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
       throw new invalid_argument("b cannot be zero!");
    }

    return a / b;
}
```

It works so far
the only problem, i get a WindowsError Exception in Python and I cannot retrieve the text 
*b cannot be zero*
Is there some special exception type I must throw? Or must the Python code be altered?
python code:

```
from ctypes import *

mathdll=cdll.MathFuncsDll
divide = mathdll.Divide
divide.restype = c_double
divide.argtypes = [c_double, c_double]

try:
    print divide (10,0)
except WindowsError:
    print "lalal"
except:
    print "dada"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through the ctypes documentation for Python 2.7.3 I can't see any reference to C++ and throwing exceptions from C++ code called via ctypes. It seems ctypes was meant for calling C functions only and does not handle C++ exceptions.

Comment: I was playing around with the throw label
trying if it change something in the behaviour...

so how should I handle exception?

Comment: One thing you can do is to give up using exceptions for communicating errors to Python code; instead use another out parameter to return error code. Not very elegant, I know... Another option is to use Swig, it has good support for handling exceptions, or Boost.Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from ctypes import *

mathdll=cdll.MathFuncsDll
divide = mathdll.Divide
divide.restype = c_double
divide.argtypes = [c_double, c_double]

try:
    print divide (10,0)
except WindowsError as we:
    print we.args[0]
except:
    print "Unhandled Exception"
```

Comment: FYI: The python interpreter terminates if the C++ exception is not properly caught. It does not magically translate to a Python exception. Python never returns from the function call that throws the exception, so it has no way to catch it with the `try`/`except` construct.