# Ctypes catching exception from C++

Tags: python, c++, exception, ctypes

I read this question [Ctypes catching exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175753/ctypes-catching-exception)
but in my case python.exe is always crashing when I try to throw exception from C++.

My code is the same like in previous question:

C++:

```
double Divide(double a, double b)
{
  if (b == 0)
  {
    throw new invalid_argument("b cannot be zero!");
  }

  return a / b;
}
```

Python:

```
from ctypes import *

mathdll=cdll.MathFuncsDll
divide = mathdll.Divide
divide.restype = c_double
divide.argtypes = [c_double, c_double]

try:
    print divide (10,0)
except WindowsError:
    print "lalal"
except:
    print "dada"
```

I use Windows 7 x64, python 2,7 and MinGW

Are there some tips or tricks how I can handle exception from C++ in python using ctypes?

Comment: None of the answers in [Ctypes catching exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175753/ctypes-catching-exception) actually explain how @nobs was able to raise an exception in Python by throwing a C++ exception. I'll probably expand my answer with a C++ example and repost it there.

Comment: This is specific to Visual C++. For MinGW it's not possible, AFAIK. A C binding needs to catch all exceptions and translate them to error return codes. Instead of using ctypes with a C API you can write a Python extension module in C++; also Cython supports [C++ exceptions](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#exceptions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ctypes doesn't support C++ exceptions, or C++ anything for that matter. Given its Windows roots, ctypes has a handler for Windows Structured Exception Handling (SEH). A library compiled with MS Visual C++ implements C++ exceptions via SEH (code `0xE06D7363`, see [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2126/How-a-C-compiler-implements-exception-handling) for implementation details), but MinGW doesn't support SEH in C and doesn't use it to implement C++ exceptions.

If you don't care about making your code cross-platform, then you can call Windows API [`RaiseException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). ctypes will route the SEH exception to a Python `OSError`. [`_call_function_pointer`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04f714765c13/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#l730) sets up the SEH handler with the `__try` and `__except` keywords (Microsoft extended C). [`SetException`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04f714765c13/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#l251) has special handling for several exception codes, and otherwise punts to `PyErr_SetFromWindowsErr(code)`.

Example:

```c
#include <Windows.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void test()
{
    RaiseException(42, 0, 0, NULL);
}
```

Test:

```python
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> lib = CDLL('./lib.dll')
>>> lib.test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [WinError 42] Windows Error 0x%X
```

(Apparently there's a bug in `PyErr_SetFromWindowsErr`. The format code `%X` isn't supported; only lowercase `%x`. Pretend the last part is `Windows Error 0x2a`.)